# xWiki 6.3. changing database (HSQL to PostgreSQL) and migrating data

Tags: postgresql, hsqldb, xwiki

I have an instance of xWiki 6.3 running on default database i.e. HSQL.

I need to move it to PostgreSQL database.

I have installed PostgreSQL and have followed following steps from documentation to point xWiki 6.3 to my new PostgreSQL database.

1 - Copied jdbc drivers at required path in xwiki

2 - In xwiki.cfg file, I have un-commented following two lines

```
xwiki.store.migration=1  (was already un-commented)
xwiki.store.migration.databases= all
```

3 - commented hsql related section in hibernate.cfg.xml and have un-commented and updated PostgreSQL related section with required information.

After that, once I start my xWiki 6.3 instance, it shows me  a home page with Add Button. However none of the existing content is visible.

I can see that all the tables are moved to postgreSQL if I connect to Database.

Also, I am unable to login with the admin account that was working when the application was running on hsql.

Any idea if I am missing something ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your process will port any existing data (i.e. the rows, ather than the tables) from one database to the other, not least because your configuration will only know about one database at a time. I suggest you follow the guidelines to [export your content as a XAR](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/ImportExport) while configured for HSQL and then import it again once you've reconfigured for PostgreSQL.